# C++ Builder - Does C++ Builder (RAD Studio) have an add a new method/function wizard?

Tags: c++builder

I'm new to C++ Builder. It seems with everything being click and code, it would have an option to add a function (method) to a class or module, similar to MFC Wizard.

I found that it has a `C++ Class Explorer` that does what I want, but it's greyed out.  The documentation for RAD Studio says this:

> Note: The C++ Class Explorer feature is only supported for the C++ classic compiler.

So, I must not be using the classic compiler, whatever that is.

So, what is the new way to do it (so it handles the prototype/declarations and function body)?  Is the new way the old way where you just manually add both in the two different modules?

Comment: "*So, I must not be using the classic compiler, whatever that is*" - see the documentation: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Compiler#Classic_Compiler